# Restrict future dates from html5 date field in mobile browser

Tags: html, date, mobile, max, min

How to restrict future dates from date picker of default HTML5 date field in mobile browser

Comment: could you just use an if statement? for example if date is more than current date throw error?

Comment: Not for selecting, for disabling the future dates